# folder modified before it existed

Tags: macos

I did a complete reinstall of OS X El Capitan last week-deleted the old Macintosh HD and installed OSX. Upon checking some hidden folders, I noticed that some files have `Date Modified` and `Created` property set to dates such as February 12 2016. I find that peculiar, because I installed OSX last week. How come I have folders on my computer that were modified even before they existed? Is this a leftover from Apple's team of engineers, meaning that they created this folder on that date?

Comment: Is it possible that you're seeing the default date that a specific folder was updated?  I know I've seen this on Windows where an update will put a created date on the folder as the date of the upgrade or a default starting date.

Comment: Quite possible indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original `Install.framework` used `pax` to deliver the payload. `pax` will attempt to preserve file metadata. `pax` was repackaged into a proprietary binary whose behavior mimics `ditto` which also preserves creation or birth time. I have files installed on my computer that have modification dates before my computer was manufactured.

Comment: As do I too. +1